# WCF RIA with SignalR

Tags: wcf-ria-services, signalr

I am looking for a sample program with WCF RIA with SignalR.
I have a Silverlight 5 application which uses WCF Ria as the backend.

We have a requirement in which when a user saves some changes to a screen, all other users connected to the server should get a notification.

Thanks for your help in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](http://chris.59north.com/post/2011/12/15/SignalR-and-Silverlight.aspx) sample for you. some of the statements are outdated because SignalR is constantly changing, but I'm sure this sample can help you.

What you actually need is to create SignalR server side code which can sample the changes which were done via the WCF RIA, so you will need to create some centralized access to data (if you don't already have one), once you got it, you just need to use the Silverlight SignalR client to connect it to the pushing mechanism.

Comment: This sample uses Asp.Net MVC as the backend code. The moment i add  SignalR dll as a reference to WCF RIA project,and run, it shows an error, Protocol Error, Missing Connection id. Does this means SignalR runs only on top an MVC application ?

Comment: it is for ASP.NET. I think I misunderstood, there is no easy way to combine them, each of them should stand by their own and if the SignalR detects changes made by the WCF service, it can push it. maybe you can use some sort of WCF Duplex or callback instead.

Comment: No luck there too :( since Duplex or callback doesnt work with WCF RIA. So i guess my only chance is to implement a polling mechanism using some timer from the client side .

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Self-host , you don't have to have ASP.NET, just deploy like mentioned in the wiki and subscribe the client to it. But you still need the SignalR code to be aware of changes.

Comment: Thank you , I will try and let you know !